# IRC bot won't connect "You have not registered"

Tags: c#, bots, irc

Anyone know why it's doing this? I've heard that it's because the NICK needs time to register, but I mean surely 10 seconds is enough? My ping to the server's about 30ms by the way. I also get a ping before i'm spammed with "You have not registered".

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace no2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient Client = new TcpClient("myip", myport);
            NetworkStream NwStream = Client.GetStream();
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(NwStream);
            StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(NwStream);
            string Data = "";

            Writer.WriteLine("USER bigkog irc NSA bigkog");
            Writer.Flush();
            Writer.WriteLine("NICK iamabot");
            Writer.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Writer.WriteLine("JOIN #root");
            while ((Data = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                System.Console.WriteLine(Data);
                if (Data.Contains(".SayHi!"))
                {
                    Writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG #root :Hello, Everyone!");
                    Writer.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    Writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG #root :Wuzzat?");
                    Writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NickServ in use on this server?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the Thread.Sleep() call - indeed this may be part of your issue.

You also need to listen for PING messages sent from the server or your connection will time out. Sometimes as part of the connection registration, a server may send a PING to a client (I can't remember which network I've seen this on, but I have seen it before), and expect a PONG back before completing connection registration.

I'd be tempted to listen as soon as you send the nick/user combo, and respond as appropriate to anything the server sends you, be it a PING, or a 001 (welcome) message. As soon as you receive the 001 message, your connection is registered and you can send the JOIN messages.

Take a look at the IRC spec (RFC1459 or RFC2812), but remember not everyone implements it correctly, so give it some leeway.